# ruby net-sftp read file line by line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sftp, net-sftp

I am using ruby 2.0.0 and rails 4.0.0. I have something similar to this:

```
require 'net/sftp'


 sftp = Net::SFTP.start('ftp.app.com','username', :password => 'password')

 sftp.file.open("/path/to/remote/file.csv", "r") do |f|
    puts f.gets
 end
```

This opens the file on the FTP site, but it only `puts` the first line of the csv file. I need to read this file row by row, preferably ignoring the header.

How can I read the file row by row, without downloading the file locally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this by doing this:

```
data = sftp.download!("/path/to/remote/file.csv").split(/\r\n/)

data.each do |line|
  puts line
end
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't seem to meet your requirement "without downloading the file?"

Comment: I edited my question to add "locally". This method just downloads the file into memory, so there is no physical copy of the file that I have to store.

Answer (score 3):

The proper answer for this would actually be to use the file.eof? value.

The code would look like:

```
require 'net/sftp'
sftp = Net::SFTP.start('ftp.app.com','username', :password => 'password')
sftp.file.open("/path/to/remote/file.csv", "r") do |f|
  while !f.eof?
    puts f.gets
  end
end
```

Documentation can be found [here](http://rubydoc.info/gems/net-sftp/Net/SFTP/Operations/File)

Answer (score 0):

In my case something like this worked:

```
data = sftp.download!("/path/to/remote/file.csv").split(/\n/).map{ |e| e.split(/,/).map{ |x| x.gsub(/"/, "")} }

data.each do |line|
  puts line
end
```

Will also split each row of the .csv into different array columns and remove any excess of "". Note this is for mac where line breaks are \n.